# Can we add scroll bar on css tooltip ?

Tags: html, css

```
<span class="field-tip"><span class="tip-content">Put help text in here!</span></span>
```

I need to add scrollbar for tooltip content which is "put help text in here!". Can anyone please help.

Comment: use `span.tip-content{ overflow:scroll; }`

Comment: can you provide a fiddle or codepen demo?

Comment: it would help to know what you're using to make the tooltip and whether you wanted a vertical or horizintal scroll

Comment: Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GYvzj/)

Comment: @DharmeshPatel  i forked your fiddle

Answer (score 0):

you could add `overflow-y: visible;` to your div definition in your css and that would work.

if you use scroll i would suggest you use overflow-y or overflow-x and not just overflow on it's own or else you get arrows in all directions

Answer (score 0):

```
overflow-y: auto
```

You'll use auto so that he only will be able to scroll if necessary. (so if the inner content takes up more space than the outer box the content lives in)

That'll do the trick.